# Why Aptana does not display classes information next to the python files in Navigator?

Tags: file, class, view, aptana

I'm using Aptana Studio 3 and Python 2.7.3. I have a project and I know that I can make Aptana show me information about the classes in each *.py file, but I do not know how to do it. ( i.e. there should be "plus" sign next to each file name and when I click it should expand and show me information about all the classes/methods/etc in the file )

Can someone tell me the steps?

P.P.: I've tried to google the information, but nothing came out : /

Comment: I don't know about Python, but for PHP, you can see the methods and classes in 'Outline' not 'Navigator'. There are also several PyDev views available like 'Hierarchy View' which may have the information you are looking for. Have you looked at the options under `Window > Show View > Other`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Sarah Kemp

To view the information in the files go to Window > Show View > Other > PyDev > PyDev Package Explorer